# Use Cookie in asp.net core mvc (Delete)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies, session-cookies

I have an asp.net mvc core application (PWA)
I want to add a cookie and delete it after user logout

*Add cookie code:*

```
Response.Cookies.Append("test", data, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)});
```

*Delete cookie code:*

```
Response.Cookies.Append("test", "", new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) });
```

of course I've used: `Response.Cookies.Delete("test");`

**but the problem when I login from 2 different browsers/devices and logout from one of the browsers/devices, after refresh the other browser/device is logged out!
I think it deletes all cookies with name "test" from all browsers/devices!!!**

Comment: This question has an answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918820/delete-cookies-in-net-core-2-0?rq=1