# How do I invalidate an authentication cookie in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I am having trouble invalidating an authentication cookie in ASP.NET Core 3.0.

**Scenario**

I have a user who is logged into the website. When they click the logout button it calls the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This successfully clears all the cookies in the browser, however, if I grab the value of the session cookie `.AspNetCore.Cookies` prior to signing out, then add it back in on a future request, I am able to navigate to the pages which require user authentication.

Anyone able to help with this?

*Note: The original question was regarding how to clear user session but I have since realised that this is actually an issue regarding the cookie itself and not server-side session.*

Comment: Have you tried Session.Abandon() ? This should just abandon the whole session

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976991/9936356 Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie)

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp ```Session.Abandon()``` doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core so I can't use that unfortunately.

@LinkedListT I believe that only deletes the cookie client-side. It appears the session still exists on the server.

Comment: There is no server-side session here. The cookie _fully_ represents the user's authenticated session. What is the _problem_ you are trying to solve here? i.e. Why is this an issue?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Lets say an attacker manages to get access to the authentication cookie stored in the browser (```.AspNetCore.Cookies```) of a different user. If they add that cookie to their request then they are able to access that users session and access areas of the site which require authentication.

Comment: @KirkLarkin So, as there isn't actually any session being stored on the server, I need to find some way of invalidating this cookie once the user logs out.

Comment: It's not something you _usually_ have to worry about. There's a very limited attack vector for a secure, http-only only cookie sent using TLS. Still, you can look at [`OnValidatePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onvalidateprincipal?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationEvents_OnValidatePrincipal) to help reject an authentication cookie, but there's no built-in support for deciding when to do so.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thank you very much for the info, I will take a look into ```OnValidatePrincipal```.

Comment: my way to solve this is to also store a guid in the cookie and in the database as a session connected to a user. if the user log out, the session in the database is beeing marked as "logged out" and then this cookie will be rejected as valid for any further authentication - the problem is that i have to validate the cookie on every request, but for my case security is important.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue as my app is failing this test: https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_logout_functionality_(OTG-SESS-006)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with signout is that it just removes the cookie, but the cookie it self is still valid.

The only solution to this is to add a Cookie SessionStore and add it to the cookie authentication handler. By adding one, you can ensure that the cookie can not be reused after signout and the second benefit is that the cookie size is also reduced.

You can add one to the cookie handler like this:

```
.AddCookie("cookie", o =>
{
    //...
    o.SessionStore = new MySessionStore();
})
```

To implement a session store, all you need to do is to implement this interaface:

```
/// <summary>
/// This provides an abstract storage mechanic to preserve the identity
/// information on the server while only sending a simple identifier
/// key to the client. This is most commonly used to mitigate
/// issues with serializing large identities into cookies.
/// </summary>
public interface ITicketStore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Store the identity ticket and return the associated key.
    /// </summary>
    Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket);

    /// <summary>
    /// Tells the store that the given identity should be updated.
    /// </summary>
    Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket);

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves an identity from the store for the given key.
    /// </summary>
    Task<AuthenticationTicket?> RetrieveAsync(string key);

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove the identity associated with the given key.
    /// </summary>
    Task RemoveAsync(string key);
}
```

More details about this and how to implement a session store can be found in my blog post at:

[Improving ASP.NET Core Security By Putting Your Cookies On A Diet](https://nestenius.se/2024/01/22/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/)

Comment: This won't invalidate previously issued and unexpired cookie.

Comment: It should, can you post your startup class in the question? perhaps you missed something there? Added some alternative solution in my answer.

Comment: It will clear cookie from the browser but if someone has intercepted that cookie he can still use it until it is expired. By default ASP.NET Core cookies are not using any server-side sessions.

Comment: can you post your Startup code?

Comment: It looks more or less like this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg/Startup.cs

Comment: Perhaps the signout code here might help? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/549#issuecomment-687659031
 "In the Task<IActionResult> SignOut([FromRoute] string scheme) method"

Comment: Fixed my answer, hope it solves your question.